# How to display current playlist/track list in Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: windows-media-player, playlists

On my work computer, Windows Media Player 12 is installed: `Version: 12.0.7601.17514`.  I'm not able to get the currently queued tracks or playlist to display like in previous versions.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: My WMP]

*Note: I've got Windows 7 with the Aero theme turned off, which is why the player looks so bland.*

Here's what I'd like to see (the "Play list" section on the right):

[image: Ideal WMP]

*Note: In my version of WMP, under the `Help` menu, the `Check for updates...` option is disabled.*

**Update**:

There is no `Library` option in the `View` menu...

[image: View Menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're now in WMP's Skin mode. To switch back to Library mode, open the **View** menu and select **Library**, then select the **Play** tab on top to show the current playlist.

**In response to the update:**

Then the group policy to prevent you from using WMP's library is probably active on your system. To deactivate it, open the Start Menu, type **gpedit.msc**, and press Enter. In the Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to **User Configuration** - **Administrative Templates** - **Windows Components** - **Windows Media Player** - **User Interface**, double-click **Set and Lock Skin** and set it to **Disabled**.

Comment: Thanks @Tim De Baets, but there is no `Library` option in the `View` menu (see screenshot in updated question).  Also clicking the little icon in the top right corner `Switch to Library` does nothing either...

Comment: Then the group policy to prevent you from using WMP's library is probably active on your system. To deactivate it, open the Start Menu, type **gpedit.msc**, and press Enter. In the Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to **User Configuration** - **Administrative Templates** - **Windows Components** - **Windows Media Player** - **User Interface**, double-click **Set and Lock Skin** and set it to **Disabled**.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the contents of your comment?  It worked beautifully!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on top of the WMP, select show list.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on song and select "add to" > playlist.
The Playing Now list should now appear in Library mode.